# UIImageView's intrinsic content size in UITableviewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, imageview, tableview

I have a Tableview Cell with an Imageview.
I want to show Image as full-size i.e. the height of image is same as actual image.

The Tableview cell height should be same as Actual image height.

**How can I achieve this?**

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have an array having image names.

Use The following method

**for Objective-C**

```
  - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            if (image == nil){
               return 36; //return any static value
            } else {
               return image.size.height;
            }
    }
```

**for Swift**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let image = UIImage(named: arrImages[indexPath.row])
    image?.size.height
    if image == nil {
        return 36  //return any static value
    } else {
        return (image?.size.height)!
    }

}
```

Comment: The same code i have used and its working for me .And make sure you are using auto resizing not auto layouts or size classes .And let me know what is the issue after using this ?